# Show travel route of multiple destinations

Tags: geographics

Suppose I have a list of cities and I want to get a picture of how to get to every city in that list from a central location like St. Louis. It would loosely resemble bicycle spokes originating from that central city. How can I do this?

Comment: [`TravelDirections`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TravelDirections.html) will give you the path, the only thing left is to build a list of `{source, destination}` and map onto it. Then use [`GeoGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html) to show them.

Comment: Here is what I have. Table2 is a list of cities paired with distance to cityCenter which can be any city in the US.

td[n_] := 
 TravelDirections[{cityCenter, table2[[n, 1]]}, 

  TravelMethod -> "Driving"]

tdGraph[n_] := 
 GeoGraphics[Style[Line[td[n]], Thick, Red], 

  GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[1.5*radius, "Miles"]]

g1 = Table[tdGraph[n], {n, 1, Length@table2}];

Show[g1]

Comment: "Here is what I have" - **edit** your question to include that code (which you should have done to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming London as our main point and three cities around that as our destinations:

```
source = Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]; 

destinations = {Entity["City", {"Dartford", "Kent", "UnitedKingdom"}],
    Entity["City", {"Woking", "Surrey", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Luton", "Luton", "UnitedKingdom"}]};
```

We could use [`Thread`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/Thread.html) to build up the list and map our function:

```
GeoGraphics[Style[Line[TravelDirections[#, TravelMethod -> "Driving"]&/@Thread[{source,destinations}]], Thick, Red]]
```

Output:

[image]